# JSON to model deserialization - custom fields only

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, deserialization

I'm developing a Django application which needs to retrieve information from a public API (JSON format). I have the following model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Let's say that the public API I'm using will return information about the first_name and last_name fields, but in addition, it will return a lot more information, like so:

```
{
"responseInfo": {
    "requestId": "777"
},
"response": {
    "people": [{
        "firstName": "First Name",
        "lastName": "Last Name",
        "coordinates": {
            "address": "Address",
            "email": "test@test.com"
        }
    },
    "firstName": "First Name",
    "lastName": "Last Name",
    "coordinates": {
        "address": "Address",
        "email": "test@test.com"
    },
    {
           ...
    }
  ]
}
```

}

How can I deserialize only the fields I need? I tried using the Django rest framework serializer, but translating the JSON into my model is never valid since I can't figure out how to omit the fields I don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just deserialize everything?

```
deserialized_data = json.loads(data)
for person in deserialized_data['response']['people']:
    # create Person here 
    # (or save values to some data structure to bulk_create later)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @Boris Uvarov. I am now able to iterate through the JSON and create my own model with the information I need.